# Must create Runnable JAR (TestNG/Maven project) from Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, jar, testng, runnable

I have created Hybrid Framework with POM approach, and now i must create Runnable JAR from Selenium that client will be able to execute from its machine. I created TestRunner:

```
package gov.gao.qa.testcases;

import org.testng.TestNG;
import gov.gao.qa.listeners.ExtentReportListener;

public class TestRunner {
    
    static TestNG testNG;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        ExtentReportListener ext = new ExtentReportListener();
        testNG = new TestNG();
        testNG.setTestClasses(new Class[] {NewBluePTest.class});
        testNG.addListener(ext); 
        testNG.run(); 
    }
}

This is my Report.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="New Blue Publishing Regression Suite" verbose="2" thread-count="2" parallel="tests">

    <listeners>
        <listener
            class-name="gov.gao.qa.listeners.ExtentReportListener" />
    </listeners>

    <test name="NBP Regression Test_chrome">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
        <classes>
            <class name="gov.gao.qa.testcases.NewBluePTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="NBP Regression Test_firefox">
        <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
        <classes>
            <class name="gov.gao.qa.testcases.NewBluePTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>



***Extent Report Listener class:***

public class ExtentReportListener extends BasePage implements ITestListener {
    private static final String OUTPUT_FOLDER = "./REPOSRTS/";
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "TestExecutionReport.html";
    private static ExtentReports extent = init();
    public static ThreadLocal<ExtentTest> test = new ThreadLocal<ExtentTest>();

    private static ExtentReports init() {
        Path path = Paths.get(OUTPUT_FOLDER);

        if (!Files.exists(path)) {
            try {
                Files.createDirectories(path); 
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(OUTPUT_FOLDER + FILE_NAME);
        htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("New Blue Publishing Automation Test Results");
        htmlReporter.config().setReportName("Automation Test Results");
        htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.TOP);
        htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);
        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
        extent.setReportUsesManualConfiguration(true);
        return extent;
    }

    public synchronized void onStart(ITestContext context) {
        System.out.println("Test Suite started!");
    }

    public synchronized void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
        System.out.println(("Test Suite is ending!"));
        extent.flush();
        test.remove();
    }

    public synchronized void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
        String methodName = result.getMethod().getMethodName();
        String qualifiedName = result.getMethod().getQualifiedName();
        int last = qualifiedName.lastIndexOf(".");
        int mid = qualifiedName.substring(0, last).lastIndexOf(".");
        String className = qualifiedName.substring(mid + 1, last);
        System.out.println(methodName + " started!");
        ExtentTest extentTest = extent.createTest(result.getMethod().getMethodName(),
                result.getMethod().getDescription());
        extentTest.assignCategory(result.getTestContext().getSuite().getName());
    
        extentTest.assignCategory(className);
        test.set(extentTest);
        test.get().getModel().setStartTime(getTime(result.getStartMillis()));
    }

    public synchronized void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println((result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " passed!"));
        test.get().pass("Test passed");
        test.get().getModel().setEndTime(getTime(result.getEndMillis()));
    }

******FAILES******

 public synchronized void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println((result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " failed!"));
        try {
            test.get().fail(result.getThrowable(),

--fail--------->    MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(getScreenshot()).build());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err
                    .println("Exception thrown while updating test fail status " + Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
        }
        test.get().getModel().setEndTime(getTime(result.getEndMillis()));
    }

    public synchronized void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println((result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " skipped!"));
        try {
            test.get().skip(result.getThrowable(),
                    MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(getScreenshot()).build());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err
                    .println("Exception thrown while updating test skip status " + Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
        }
        test.get().getModel().setEndTime(getTime(result.getEndMillis()));
    }

    public synchronized void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println(("onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage for " + result.getMethod().getMethodName()));
    }

    private Date getTime(long millis) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(millis);
        return calendar.getTime();
    }
}

****Base page****


    public WebDriver driver;
    public Properties prop;
    public static boolean highlightElement;
    public OptionsManager optionsManager;

    By OpenForm = By.xpath("//button[@class='open-button']");
    By JobcodeField = By.id("jobCode");
    By DraftHTML = By.xpath("//input[@value='Draft HTML']");
    By HideForm = By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Hide Form')]");
    
    public static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> tldriver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();
    
    public static synchronized WebDriver getDriver() {
        return tldriver.get(); 
    }

    public WebDriver init_driver(Properties prop) {
        String browserName = null;
        if (System.getProperty("browser") == null) {
            browserName = prop.getProperty("browser");
        } else {
            browserName = System.getProperty("browser");
        }
        
        highlightElement = prop.getProperty("highlight").equals("yes") ? true : false;
        System.out.println("Browser Launched:" + " " + browserName);
        optionsManager = new OptionsManager(prop);

//  public WebDriver init_driver(String browserName) {
//      highlightElement = prop.getProperty("highlight").equals("yes") ? true : false;
//      System.out.println("Browser Launched:" + " " + browserName); 
//      optionsManager = new OptionsManager(prop); 

        if (browserName.equals("chrome")) {
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            tldriver.set(new ChromeDriver(optionsManager.getChromeOptions()));

        } else if (browserName.equals("firefox")) {
            WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
            tldriver.set(new FirefoxDriver(optionsManager.getFirefoxOptions()));

        } else if (browserName.equals("internetexplorer")) {
            WebDriverManager.iedriver().setup();
            tldriver.set(new InternetExplorerDriver(optionsManager.io));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Browser Name" + " " + browserName + "is not found");
        }
 
        getDriver().manage().deleteAllCookies();
        getDriver().manage().window().maximize();
        
        if(System.getProperty("url") == null) {
            getDriver().get(prop.getProperty("url"));
        }else {
            getDriver().get(System.getProperty("url"));
        }
        return getDriver();
    } 

    public Properties init_properties() {
        prop = new Properties();
        String path = null;
        String env = null;

        try {
            env = System.getProperty("env");

            if (env.equals("qa")) {
                path = "./src/main/java/gov/gao/qa/config/qa.config.properties";
            } else if (env.equals("dev")) {
                path = "./src/main/java/gov/gao/qa/config/dev.config.properties";
            } else if (env.equals("demo")) {
                path = "./src/main/java/gov/gao/qa/config/demo.config.properties";
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            path = "./src/main/java/gov/gao/qa/config/config.properties";
        }
        try {
            FileInputStream ip = new FileInputStream(path);
            prop.load(ip);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Configuration Propoeries Issue... correct config.properties file");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return prop;
    }


    public String getScreenshot() {
 File src = ((TakesScreenshot) getDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE); <-----failes
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/screenshots/" + System.currentTimeMillis() +".png";
        File destination = new File(path);
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(src, destination);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("screenshot captured failed...");
        }
        return path;
    }
}
```

When i execute the testRunner it gives me:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at gov.gao.qa.base.BasePage.getScreenshot(BasePage.java:284)
at gov.gao.qa.listeners.ExtentReportListener.onTestFailure(ExtentReportListener.java:89)

ExtentReport was copied from website, i am very new to this. Please help.

Comment: tldriver looks like it's an uninitialized webdriver to me... check to see if getDriver() is working...

Comment: it does, because i am able to execute script using TestNG Suite

Comment: I also downgraded the TestNG from 7.0.0 to 6.14.3, i was thinking that ExtentReport methods were different with 6.14.3 version of TestNG